# VueJS (TypeScript) component with mapBox

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, mapbox-gl-js, maplibre-gl

I'm trying to integrate a map from MapBox (or maplibre) within a VueJS component.

The thing is, I need to declare my map in the data part, but the div that will contain my map is not initialized yet. So I have to instantiate my Map inside the `mounted()` block.

I've tried this:

```js
<template>
  <div id="mapContainer" class="basemap"></div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import maplibregl from "maplibre-gl";
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "BaseMap",
  data() {
    return {
      map: null satisfies maplibregl.Map | null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.map = new maplibregl.Map({
      container: "mapContainer",
      style:
        `https://api.maptiler.com/maps/voyager-v2/style.json?key=` +
        import.meta.env.VITE_MAP_TOKEN,
      center: [15, 56.5],
      zoom: 3.6,
    });
  },
  methods(): {},
});
</script>
```

But I'm getting `TS2322: Type 'Map' is not assignable to type 'null'.` and `TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.` on all calls on `this.map`.

Is there an easy way to force to type of `this.map` or do this in a cleaner way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`satisfies` won't work.  It will set the narrowest type it can set, in this case, the type of `map` is set to `null`.

You can see that error on this simple TypeScript example

```js
let y = null satisfies number | null;
y = 123; // error Type '123' is not assignable to type `null`
```

I would recommend using an interface to define all the types of the properties in the data

```js
<template>
  <div id="mapContainer" class="basemap"></div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import maplibregl from "maplibre-gl";
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

interface Data {
    map: maplibregl.Map | null;
}

export default defineComponent<Data>({
  name: "BaseMap",
  data() {
    return {
      map: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.map = new maplibregl.Map({
      container: "mapContainer",
      style:
        `https://api.maptiler.com/maps/voyager-v2/style.json?key=` +
        import.meta.env.VITE_MAP_TOKEN,
      center: [15, 56.5],
      zoom: 3.6,
    });
  },
  methods(): {},
});
</script>
```

For the `TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.` error you need to use either optional chaining (`?.`) or non-null assertion (`!.`) e.g.

```js
this.map?.moveLayer('id', 'beforeId');
this.map!.moveLayer('id', 'beforeId');
```